# Flutter widget test

Tags: flutter, testing, widget

i need help for flutter widget testing , in my Login screen i have a drop down button form field wraped in visibility . it will be populated when we enter a valid email and on focus change it will call an api to fetch business. how to test this widget scenario. please help

I tried it using mock api call but the drop down list is not generating. the below code is to be tested:

```dart
child: Field(
                        validator: (val) {
                          bool emailValid =
                              RegExp(emailPattern).hasMatch(val.toString());
                      }
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          emailValue = val;
                          isValidEmail = true;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        controller: emailCtrl,
                      ),
                      onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                        if (!hasFocus) {
                         
                          bool emailValid = RegExp(emailPattern)
                              .hasMatch(emailValue.toString());
                          if (emailValid) {
                            isValidEmail = true;
                            BusinessController()
                                .fetchBusiness(
                                    emailValue) 
                                .then((value) {
                              if (value!.data.businessIds.length > 0) {
                                if (value.data.businessIds.length == 1) {
                                  businessIds = value.data.businessIds;
                                  selectedBusinessId =
                                      value.data.businessIds[0].businessId!;
                                  selectedBusinessObject = businessIds[0];
                                } else {
                                  setState(() {
                                    businessIds = value.data.businessIds;
                                    businessIds.insert(
                                        0, initialBusinessObject);
                                    selectedBusinessId =
                                        businessIds[0].businessId!;
                                    selectedBusinessObject = businessIds[0];
                                  });
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          } 
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
               
                  Visibility(
                    // visible: businessIds.isNotEmpty && businessIds.length > 1,
                    visible: true,
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                      key: Key('business'),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: CustomColors.black12,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: CustomColors.black12,
                          ),
                        ),
                        label: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "Select BusinessId",
                              style: CustomTheme.text_14_700_secoundaryColor),
                          const TextSpan(
                              text: '*',
                              style: CustomTheme.text_14_700_primaryColor)
                        ])),
                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                        hintText: "Select Business",
                      ),
                      value: selectedBusinessId,
                      style: CustomTheme.normal
                          .copyWith(color: CustomColors.basicColor1),
                      onChanged: businessIds.length == 1
                          ? (val) {
                              initialBusinessObject.businessId;
                            }
                          : (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedBusinessId = val as int;
                              });
                              pickBusinessId();
                              debugPrint(
                                  "usertype : ${selectedBusinessObject.businessName} - ${selectedBusinessObject.userType}");
                            },
                      items: businessIds
                          .map((businessIdname) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: businessIdname.businessId,
                              child: Text(
                                  "${businessIdname.businessName}".isEmpty
                                      ? "${businessIdname.name}"
                                      : "${businessIdname.businessName}")))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Please add testing code to understand what could be wrong